Conda is looking in the wrong directory
I am trying to run Anaconda on Windows via the Miniconda installation. Currently I cannot run any conda commands, as I believe a directory was specified wrong somewhere, but not in my PATH variable. When I open my Git Bash terminal and type "conda," I get the following message (assume my username is "myname"):
bash: C:\Usersyname\miniconda3\Scripts: No such file or directory

I immediately noticed the typo: "Usersyname" should be "Users\myname". I figured I made a mistake adding miniconda to my PATH, so I went to fix it, but everything looks fine there, i.e. all miniconda-relevant paths are specified "C:\Users\myname\...". However, when i run echo $PATH, the first entries are all miniconda paths with the same typo ("Usersyname"):
C:\Usersyname\miniconda3vs\ml;C:\Usersyname\miniconda3vs\ml\Library\mingw-w6in;C:\Usersyname\miniconda3vs\ml\Library\usin;C:\Usersyname\miniconda3vs\ml\Librarin;C:\Usersyname\miniconda3vs\ml\Scripts;C:\Usersyname\miniconda3vs\min;C:\Usersyname\miniconda3/c/Users/myname/bin

How are these paths ending up in my $PATH environment variable? And where can I correct this?

Do you have a file called .bashrc in your home directory (your home directory is probably C:\Users\myname in this case) - it is a hidden file make sure you know how to view hidden files. If you find this file, what is its contents?
